# Stable homotopy of spheres non-locally

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, soft-question

Are there any results/conjectures about the stable homotopy groups of spheres that relate the picture at different primes? Something like Gauss's reciprocity law in number theory?

I know about the Drozd-Kolesnyk cancellation in the stable homotopy category, which is definitely a non-local result, but it is not about the stable homotopy groups of spheres.
Probably, there are many non-local things in the theory of ring spectra (because it contains ring theory). So my question is restricted to the stable homotopy groups of spheres.

Comment: Greenlees and I discovered some tantalizing and still unexplored indications of such connections using topological Amitsur-Dress-Tate cohomology in our Memoir ``Generalized Tate cohomology.  See Examples 24.17 there.

Comment: You should look at the work of Dustin Clausen:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5851